# Box.com API without user interaction

Tags: box-api

I'm developing a google connector (for google search appliance), and I need to do the authentication to box.com but without having to do the login, and allow pages. Perhaps is a duplicate to: [Box API Login issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672589/box-api-login-issue/12392831)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this. You will have to retrieve your token using the OAuth2 flow the first time. Then you will need to store the access token in your database along with it's refresh token. The Access token expires in 1 hour. The refresh token expires in 14 days. You can use the refresh token to get a new access token every time you need to make a request bypassing the user authentication flow. You will just need to make sure, your refresh token is used within 14 days. You are better off setting a cron that refreshes your tokens.

I've built this in my application so just build this out and your app will work well.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Box API is currently only accessible after authenticating a user through [OAuth 2](http://developers.box.com/oauth)